# mysql query order by id desc plus if a value is less then on top

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

my query fetches results by id descending but what i wish is say by default new entry results show by id desc on top whenever page is refreshed but if any value in already added data in quantity column is less than 2 then it should displays on top then followed by new entries order by id desc

```
SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id DESC, quantity <2 DESC
```

I tried that but does not seem to be working.

Comment: Examples of how you want the data sorted would help.

Comment: Absolutely unclear... show some source data and desired output, or something...

Comment: sorry guy im very bad at explaining i tried my best

Comment: say i added a data it get stored and id is 1, then 2 then 3 and it displays by 3, 2, 1 order but now say i added another entry 4 but in id 2 the quantity field has a value 1 then the order should be 2, 4, 3, 1

Comment: Flip the 2 expressions of the ORDER BY clause: `ORDER BY quantity < 2 DESC, id DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check  the condition in order by  prior of the id

```
       SELECT * 
       FROM product 
       ORDER BY case when quantity <2 then 0 else 1 end desc,
       id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks alot it does but now what it i wanted to increase the less than value from 1 to 5?

Comment: you comment  .. is not clear   change the question and add changing comment is not fair  . SO is a question/answer  site  ..  not a fre coding service

Comment: Its in the same question i guess as i tried changing less than value from 2 to 5 then things are getting messed. so i asked what is the procedure?

Comment: You mean  ORDER BY case when quantity between 1 AND 5   then 0 else 1 end desc ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query:

```
select * ,(case when quantity<2 then 1 else 2 end)priority, row_number()over (order by id desc) rown from product
order by priority,rown
```

or if you want to avoid priority and rownumber in your result you can use cte as below:

```
with cte as (select * ,(case when quantity<2 then 1 else 2 end)priority, row_number()over (order by id desc) rown from product
    )
select col1,col2.... from cte order by priority,rown
```